# Using WPF template in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="currencyColumn">
        <StackPanel Height="210" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <Image Height="64" Source="assets/images/chaos.png"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="total" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Total}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="48" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="used" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="48" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="payed" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="48" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="owed" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Owed}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="48" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

What i want to do is to add to a `ListBox`an undefined number of times this template at `runtime` via `codebehind`, each with the source of the image modified and i would like to bind the `textbox` with `readonly` tag to some variables.

Comment: In WPF you can archieve this without having to use template in code behind, I suggest you to use the Binding, to ObservableCollection as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a point to bind this through code behind, when you can do it just directly in the View(xaml).

I suppose you have a certain model to show this data in your UI:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string ImageSource {get;set;}
    public double Total {get;set;} 
    public double Used {get;set;} 
    public double Paid {get;set;} 
    public double Owed {get;set;} 
}
```

In your VM, you would have a collection of this, since you said you will have a undefined number of them.

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
public class MyVM : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModelCollection
    {
       get {return _myModelCollection;}
       set {SetProperty(ref _myModelCollection);}
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _myModelCollection;
}
```

Lastly, in your View (xaml)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelCollection, Mode=OneWay}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource currencyColumn}">
</ItemsControl>
```

Here I am using your already defined DataTemplate.

Comment: Thanks i will try that, though when i type `DataTemplate` in `ItemsControl ` i get an error `"DataTemplate" is not recognized or not accessible`

Comment: What i did was move the template in the `ItemsControl` instead with a `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`, i have made it work except for one thing, using `ItemsSource` directly in the `ItemsControl` does not seem to be working, i have to do it in the codebehind using `NameOfItemsControl.ItemsSource = MyModelCollection`, i can't find out why.

Comment: One of the reasons I can think of is that you are probably not firing a PropertyChanged event from the VM's property. My example is using Prism's SetProperty which does it internally.

Comment: I think i see what you mean, i definitely need to understand this more, thanks for the help.